# How to edit /etc/hosts file in running docker container

Tags: docker, centos7

I am working on an application which requires some  configuration to be stored in /etc/hosts file of a docker container.
I have tried it with many options but did not find any correct way of modifying the /etc/hosts file at run time.

I want to do it either by Dockerfile or by java code.
I am able to build the docker image and modify the /etc/hosts files manually, but unfortunately that is not our projects requirement.

Comment: Putting this change in the Dockerfile would modify the image, not the running container. Are you trying to modify the /etc/host from commands running inside of the container or on the host system?

Comment: Yes, If it is possible. I have also tried this using the upgraded version of  docker in which they have CreateContainerCmd class which contains a function called withExtraHosts(String ...hosts), but that did'not worked too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recommended solution is to use the `--add-host` option to `docker run` or the equivalent in the `docker-compose.yml` file if you're using docker-compose.

BUT, I was in the same boat as you. I have a script that modifies the hosts file that I wanted to run in the container, so what I did was `COPY` the script into the container and make it executable, then in the Dockerfile's `CMD` script that your choose, call your script to modify the hosts file

### Works

in Dockerfile

```
# add the modifyHostsFile script, make it executable
COPY ./bash-scripts/modifyHostsFile.sh /home/user/modifyHostsFile.sh
RUN sudo chmod +x /home/user/modifyHostsFile.sh


# run the script that starts services
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/home/user/run.sh"]
```

And in the `run.sh` script I execute that script to modify the hosts file

```
# modify the hosts file
bash ./modifyHostsFile.sh
```

### Doesn't Work

in Dockerfile

```
# add the modifyHostsFile script, make it executable
COPY ./bash-scripts/modifyHostsFile.sh /home/user/modifyHostsFile.sh
RUN sudo chmod +x /home/user/modifyHostsFile.sh

# modify the hosts file right now
RUN bash /home/user/modifyHostsFile.sh    

# run the script that starts services
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/home/user/run.sh"]
```

---

You have to run the script that modifies your hosts file during your `CMD` script. If you run it via `RUN bash ./modifyHostsFile.sh` in your Dockerfile it will be added to that container, but then Docker will continue to the next step in the Dockerfile and create a new container (it creates a new intermediary container for each step in the Dockerfile) and your changes to the `/etc/hosts` will be overridden.

Answer (score 10):

Depends upon what sort of modifications you want to do. If you just need to add more hosts, you can probably do it within docker run command like -

```
docker run --add-host="localA:127.0.0.1" --add-host="localB:172.0.0.1" ....
```

This link might be useful as well :- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10324

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and overcome it with `vi` in `ex` mode.

`ex -sc '%s/foo/bar/g|x' /etc/hosts`