# Modifying the hosts file of a running docker container

Tags: linux, docker

I need to add an entry to /etc/hosts file of a running container and get it applied same time. I manually modified the hosts file but the change did not get reflected on container. Is there any other we can do this? I want to do this without restarting the container.

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860601/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file-in-running-docker-container)

Comment: Thanks @Terminus I could not find anything useful there. I want to get this applied to a running container.

Answer (score 0):

if you check `docker inspect {contaner id}`
as you can see it's different network subnet on your host.
because of docker will create totally sandbox environment for you.

it will give you random IP when you docker up everytime.

so I recommend you use docker-compose to help you build your multi-services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could not relate it to my question. Appreciate if you could explain more in detail.