# Running ElasticSearch and Kibana on K8s Error - Kibana did not load properly. Check the server output for more information

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana

I'm trying to run Elasticsearch and Kibana on Kubernetes cluster (same namepace). I created Pod and a Service for Elasticsearch and for Kibana. When I enter to the elasticsearch website (http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/elasticsearch/proxy/), everything seems fine, but when I enter to Kibana's website, I see **"Kibana did not load properly. Check the server output for more information.".**

The Kibana pod's logs, are the following:

```
{"type":"error","@timestamp":"2019-03-04T19:27:21Z","tags":["warning","stats-collection"],"pid":1,"level":"error","error":{"message":"Request Timeout after 30000ms","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms\n    at /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:355:15\n    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:384:7)\n    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)\n    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)\n    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)\n    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)"},"message":"Request Timeout after 30000ms"}
```

Those are the yaml files:

**deployment_elasticsearch.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    service: elasticsearch
spec:
  ports:
  containers:
  - name: elasticsearch
    image: elasticsearch:6.6.1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9200
    - containerPort: 9300
    env:
    - name: discovery.type
      value: "single-node"
```

**deployment_elasticsearch_service.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    service: elasticsearch
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    name: serving
  - port: 9300
    name: node-to-node
  selector:
    service: elasticsearch
```

**deployment_kibana.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kibana
  labels:
    service: kibana
spec:
  ports:
  containers:
  - name: kibana
    image: kibana:6.6.1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5601
```

**deployment_kibana_service.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana
  labels:
    service: kibana
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5601
    name: serving
  selector:
    service: kibana
```

Also, when I enter to kibana pod, and run "$curl http://elasticsearch:9200", I get the elasticsearch home page (so I think that kibana can reach elasticsearch).

EDIT
This is the grep error logs for kibana:

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-03-04T22:41:16Z","tags":["status","plugin:index_management@6.6.1","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from green to red - Request Timeout after 30000ms","prevState":"green","prevMsg":"Ready"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-03-04T22:41:16Z","tags":["status","plugin:index_lifecycle_management@6.6.1","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from green to red - Request Timeout after 30000ms","prevState":"green","prevMsg":"Ready"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-03-04T22:41:16Z","tags":["status","plugin:rollup@6.6.1","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from green to red - Request Timeout after 30000ms","prevState":"green","prevMsg":"Ready"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-03-04T22:41:16Z","tags":["status","plugin:remote_clusters@6.6.1","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from green to red - Request Timeout after 30000ms","prevState":"green","prevMsg":"Ready"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-03-04T22:41:16Z","tags":["status","plugin:cross_cluster_replication@6.6.1","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from green to red - Request Timeout after 30000ms","prevState":"green","prevMsg":"Ready"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-03-04T22:41:16Z","tags":["status","plugin:reporting@6.6.1","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from green to red - Request Timeout after 30000ms","prevState":"green","prevMsg":"Ready"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-03-04T22:41:34Z","tags":["spaces","error"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to navigate to space \"default\", redirecting to Space Selector. Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-03-04T22:41:41Z","tags":["spaces","error"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to navigate to space \"default\", redirecting to Space Selector. Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms"}
```

From online research, I think that the problem is that els and kibana can't talk to one another. Can you know why?

Edit 2, describe logs:

```
kubectl describe pod kibana
Name:               kibana
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               minikube/10.0.2.15
Start Time:         Tue, 05 Mar 2019 00:21:23 +0200
Labels:             service=kibana
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 172.17.0.5
Containers:
  kibana:
    Container ID:   docker://7eecb30b2f197120706d790e884db44696d5d1a30d3ec48a9ca2a6255eca7e8a
    Image:          kibana:6.6.1
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://kibana@sha256:a2b329d8903978069632da8aa85cc5199c5ab2cf289c48b7851bafd6ee58bbea
    Port:           5601/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 05 Mar 2019 00:21:24 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL:  http://elasticsearch:9200
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-q25px (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-q25px:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-q25px
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  51m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/kibana to minikube
  Normal  Pulled     51m   kubelet, minikube  Container image "kibana:6.6.1" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    51m   kubelet, minikube  Created container
  Normal  Started    51m   kubelet, minikube  Started container
```

Comment: try to add  env to kibana: name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL value: http://elasticsearch:9200

Comment: @Amityo weird, I get "Error: 'dial tcp 172.11.0.6:5601: connect: connection refused'
Trying to reach: 'http://172.11.0.6:5601/'. I'm trying t fix it

Comment: UPDATE: Doesn't work

Comment: can you share the kubectl logs of kibana?

Comment: hi, @Amityo I edited my question

Comment: can you also share kubectl describe of kibana?

Comment: I ran "kubectl describe kibana", and got "error: the server doesn't have a resource type "kibana" "

Comment: I meant - kubectl describe pod <kibana-pod-name> and the same for the logs: kubectl get <kibana-pod-name> (without the <> )

Comment: `kubectl describe pods/kibana` or `kubectl describe services/kibana`

Comment: Oh.. I added it to the question

Comment: I'm pretty new with kubernetes, I wouldn't be surprised wrote something wrong in the yamls.

Answer (score 2):

I reproduced your setup in my cluster. And the connectivity between kibana and elasticsearch is fine.

```
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
elasticsearch                       1/1     Running   0          37m   10.244.1.8    worker-12   <none>           <none>
kibana                              1/1     Running   0          25m   10.244.3.10   worker-14   <none>           <none>
```

Ping from kibana to elasticsearch

```
bash-4.2$ ping 10.244.1.8
PING 10.244.1.8 (10.244.1.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.244.1.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.705 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.1.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=0.501 ms
```

Ping from elasticsearch to kibana

```
[root@elasticsearch elasticsearch]# ping 10.244.3.10
PING 10.244.3.10 (10.244.3.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.244.3.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.444 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.3.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=0.462 ms
```

The problem you are facing is because of the hostnames used. The kibana.yml uses the 'elasticsearch' in the elastic URL -- http://elasticsearch:9200 --. The kibana container is not able to resolve the name 'elasticsearch'.

So you will have to add an entry in to /etc/hosts file, mentioning IP address of 'elasticsearch'. For e.g. in my case, in /etc/hosts

```
# Kubernetes-managed hosts file.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
10.244.3.10     kibana
10.244.1.8 elasticsearch
```

That should solve your problem.

But, that won't be easy, you will not be able to change that file, you will have to rebuild your image or run the container with --add-host options. [look here for --add-host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860601/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file-in-running-docker-container)

A simpler work around is changing the kibana.yml, to look like this,

```
# Default Kibana configuration from kibana-docker.

server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
elasticsearch.url: http://10.244.1.8:9200 #enter your elasticsearch container IP
xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true
```

---

Configure the correct IP address of elasticsearch container and restart your kibana container. The vice-versa applies to elasticsearch container.

Take your pick.

Further edit.

To change the hosts file from k8s yml,

Start the elastic service/cluster before hand,

```
[root@controller-11 test-dir]# kubectl get services elasticsearch -o wide
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE    SELECTOR
elasticsearch   ClusterIP   10.103.254.157   <none>        9200/TCP,9300/TCP   153m   service=elasticsearch
```

Then go on to edit the kibana.yml file with IP address of elasticsearch service. It would look like this,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kibana
  labels:
    service: kibana
spec:
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "10.103.254.157"
    hostnames:
    - "elasticsearch"
  ports:
  containers:
  - name: kibana
    image: kibana:6.6.1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5601
```

Login to your kibana container and checkout the /etc/hosts file, it would look like this,

```
bash-4.2$ cat /etc/hosts
# Kubernetes-managed hosts file.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
10.244.2.2      kibana

# Entries added by HostAliases.
10.103.254.157      elasticsearch
```

Then try reaching out to the elastic server, it would look like this,

```
bash-4.2$ curl http://elasticsearch:9200
{
  "name" : "tyqNRro",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "tFmM2Nq9RDmGlDy6G2FUZw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.6.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "1fd8f69",
    "build_date" : "2019-02-13T17:10:04.160291Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

That should do it I suppose.

Further edit.

Upon further investigation, looks like the configuration you used should work without any changes i suggested. 
Looks like your k8s elasticsearch service is not configured properly. if the service is configured properly then we should find the endpoints configured to your elastic search container. It should look like this,

```
root@server1d:~# kubectl describe service elasticsearch
Name:              elasticsearch
Namespace:         default
Labels:            service=elasticsearch
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"service":"elasticsearch"},"name":"elasticsearch","namespace"...
Selector:          service=elasticsearch
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.102.227.86
Port:              serving  9200/TCP
TargetPort:        9200/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.1.9:9200
Port:              node-to-node  9300/TCP
TargetPort:        9300/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.1.9:9300
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! can I do it in the kubernetes yaml, instead of entering the container?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. First start your elasticsearch cluster. Get the IP address of the elastic container, edit the kibana.yml with hostAliases, that will add the entry in to /etc/hosts. Editing answer for full details.

Comment: Do you need the address of the container, or the service?

Comment: The container IP or service IP should be fine. But since you are already running the service, it would be more logical to add the service IP address.