# Accessing host computer's etc/hosts file inside of Docker not working

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, dockerfile

I added an alias hostname to **etc/hosts**... something like `127.0.0.1 test.site` and want to view it on the browser. I'm currently using Docker Desktop for Windows with a WSL2 environment setup.

I've tried running:

`docker run -it --add-host=test.site:127.0.0.1 ubuntu` and `docker run --add-host wrapper.local:127.0.0.1 -p 4000:80 -ti ubuntu /bin/bash`

... and when I run it on the browser I get the error *This site can't be reached*

I've also tried writing in a **Dockerfile** something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENTRYPOINT umount /etc/hosts && echo '127.0.0.1 test.site' > /etc/hosts && bash
```

... and then running:

`docker run --privileged -it -p 3000:80 sample-site`

In that case, I was trying to connect the computer's /etc/hosts to the container but I still got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit /etc/hosts file in running docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860601/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file-in-running-docker-container)

Comment: What is your host OS (I suppose is MacOS) ? Witch version ? Witch version of Docker ? Generally speaking you must configure your (MacOS) DNS to point to the container into you must install a DNS server. For configure the container DNS check [this link](https://l-lin.github.io/post/2018/2018-09-03-docker_ubuntu_18_dns/)