# script to automate adding hosts to a docker container

Tags: linux, bash, docker, dockerfile

Does anyone perhaps know how to create a script to automatically type in /etc/hosts on a container so that it takes an IP address something like HOST=$(hostname -i) and then
echo "hello $HOST" >> /etc/hosts but unfortunately this simple script doesn't work and I don't know much how to add these hosts automatically I mean of course it should happen inside the container, I know there is something like extra_hosts but I will have a lot of these containers so I would like to automate this somehow

It is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

echo "HOST=$(hostname -i)"
echo "$HOST"
echo "Hello $HOST" >> /etc/hosts
```

and Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.65

RUN mkdir ipscript
COPY script.sh ipscript/
WORKDIR ipscript/
CMD sh sctr.sh
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40430182/17650498 — is it what are you looking for?

Comment: Maintaining `/etc/hosts` files across multiple environments at scale isn't really sustainable; I'd avoid modifying this file if at all possible.  `hostname -i` inside the container will also return the mostly-unusable Docker-internal IP address, which won't be useful for you.  What's your goal with this change?  Can you set up a Domain Name Service (DNS) server, or use a cloud-hosted system like Amazon Route 53?